# Find List View in fragment from Activity

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock, fragment

in my application I use SherlockActionBar with tab navigation.
In the activity MyFragmentActivity that extend SherlockFragmentActivity I add 3 tab with the fragment

```
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(
            bar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.filmtab)),
            FragmentFilm.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(
            bar.newTab()
                    .setText(getString(R.string.cinematab)),
            FragmentCinema.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(
            bar.newTab()
                    .setText(getString(R.string.dintornitab)),
            FragmentPdi.class, null);
```

The FragmentPdi class have this code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_pdi_info, container, false);

    return view;
}
```

and the layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_places"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 
    </ListView>  


</RelativeLayout>
```

In the MyFragmentActivity I want find the listview for populate it in this way:

```
final ListView elencoPlaces = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_places);
```

....

but I have `NullPointerException`!

Why??

In the other fragment (FragmentFilm and FragmentCinema) I have other view like textview without this
problem!!

Please help me!
Thank you.

P.S. Is this the correct way for populate dinamically the views in fragment, or I must populate the view in the fragment class?? If the second how I can pass varible from the activity to the fragment??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all you have in the layout file is a listview, don't bother overriding oncreateview. the default layout will give you that much. then you can use the methods built into the ListFragment - like getListView() and setListAdapter().

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Sorry but I don‘t understand, must I use in FragmentPdi a ListFragment instead of Fragment!? Please can you explain me how whit an example!? Thank you.

Comment: just have FragmentPdi extend SherlockListFragment instead of SherlockFragment. remove your onCreateView method. when you need to get the listview, call getListView() on the FragmentPdi.

Comment: Ok thank you, but I need to get an populate the listview in the MyFragmentActivity. How I can get it on this activity???

Comment: listFragment.getListView() or listFragment.setListAdapter(). just keep a reference to your fragments, then you can call `fragment.getListView()`. if you save the references as regular fragments, you will have to cast the FragmentPdi instance to a ListFragment so it would be `((ListFragment)fragment).getListView()`

Comment: How I can keep reference to my fragment?? Sorry but I'm new in android programming!!

Comment: i'm going to assume you are using the ActionBarSherlock fragments tabs sample code as a base. you could change the addTab method to return a fragment, or make a second version that takes a fragment object instead of a class. then you could create your own fragment, save a reference, then pass it to the addTab method.

Comment: Ok, but I dont undestand why I have another fragment the FragmentCinema where I have this xml:

Answer (score 0):

Ok, but I dont undestand why I have another fragment the FragmentCinema where I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:paddingTop="10dip" android:id="@+id/otherCinemas" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/plotSeparatorOtherCin" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/txtProgrammation">
        <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:background="@drawable/palm_divider_line" android:layout_width="20.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip" />
        <TextView android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/altricinema" android:textStyle="bold" />
         <ImageView android:id="@+id/showOtherCinemas" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:src="@drawable/ic_action_freccia_cinema"
          />
       <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:background="@drawable/palm_divider_line" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listOtherCinemas"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/plotSeparatorOtherCin"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this code of class:

```
public class FragmentCinema extends SherlockFragment
```

{

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_cinema_info, container, false);

    return view;
}
```

}

and when I use the findViewbyId
final ListView cinemasOther = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listOtherCinemas);
 it works! But in FragmentPdi dont work!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ListView in ListFragments, your ListView must have id `android:id="@+id/android:list`"!

Comment: You may want to consider expanding on this answer to improve its usefulness